# How to detect scroll event in mat-list in Angular

Tags: angular, scroll, mat-list

I have a mat-list element defined like so:

```
<mat-list #wholeList class="syslog__list">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let entry of filteredLogs; let i = index">
      <mat-list-item>
      .
      .
      .
```

and so I can access it in my .ts file if needs be with:

```
@ViewChild('wholeList') wholeList: any;
```

How can I detect when the user scrolls the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(scroll)="onScroll($event)"` on your `mat-list` to handle the scroll events.

```
<mat-list #wholeList class="syslog__list" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let entry of filteredLogs; let i = index">
   <mat-list-item>
   .
   .
   .
```

By using (scroll)="onScroll($event)" on the mat-nav list, every time the user scrolls past this `mat-list`, the `onScroll` method will be called, which allows to handle event scrolling and perform all desired actions in Angular component.

**[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-qdus1u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**